# How to add checkbox to my recyclerviewer xml?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, checkbox, android-recyclerview

I created Recyclerviewer inside the fragment. Viewer consists of 2 textviews - vertical and I have underline divider under those textviews. How can I add checkbox which will be right of my first textview, but keep second textview as a same group so I don't get 2 underline dividers? More details on this image: [image]

item_tab1 xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Item1Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ïtem 1"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SubName"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/Item1SubName">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your layout in a RelativeLayout like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Item1Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ïtem 1"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SubName"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/Item1SubName">
    </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you found my answer correct can i ask you to click the tick on the left hand side of the answer to say it's correct. For more information on what to do when someone answers your question click here: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers